# opencv face recognizer, error: 'setLabelInfo' is not a member of 'cv::FaceRecognizer'

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I am making a face recognizer using opencv, i want to set a string for each label using the function (setlabelinfo) but i got the error: 'setLabelInfo' is not a member of 'cv::FaceRecognizer' , can anyone help please :)

Comment: looks like a simple typo, it is [setLabelsInfo](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/contrib/include/opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp#L957) instead.

Comment: No thats not the problem i wrote it in the code in the correct way, also the editor don't show it in the auto complete suggestions

Comment: it was an updating problem < i update opencv  to opencv 3.1 and now it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:
Yes. It isn't his member->it's member of `Ptr<FaceRecognizer>`'s member.
You'll first write `Ptr<FaceRecognizer> facerec =` `FisherFaceRecognizer::create()` or `EigenFaceRecognizer::create()`;
Then use `facerec->SetLabelInfo()`;